# None of these files exist when import dynamic image in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using array to store dynamic image. All images I saved in `images` folder (number 1 in image above). I stay in `AddInfoScreen.js` and import these image using `require` (number 2 in image above). Then I used `<Image source={e.img}/>` (number 3 and 4 in image above) but it caused an error (number 5 in image above). I have tried to change the file name `JPG` to `jpg` but still not work. Any solution for this issue, thank you all!
[image: None of these files exist]

Comment: I think, the image path can not get proper, please check it

Comment: Some points are that you can think of

1. Require and imports are done at very start (when screen is not even rendered yet).

2. May be image is taking sometime to get written, you try a delay between image write and pushing it into array.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got an answer. I know this is a newbie question aka dumb question but I hope can help to others when make a tiny mistake like I did.

The solution is change all the `*.JPG` file to `*.jpg` in `images` folder, also change in code. NO CAPITALIZATION. It's gonna work.